# How to keep time index when using DolphinDB Python API

Tags: python, dolphindb

When I upload a pandas.DataFrame with a time index like:

```
    index   |   value
 ===========|===========
 2019-02-03 |    3.9
 2019-02-04 |    4.0
```

to DolphinDB server, the index seems to be dropped in DolphinDB Python API:

```
    value
 ===========
     3.9
     4.0
```

How to keep the time index?

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB database does not import pandas.DataFrame's index. To keep the index column in DolphinDB, you can use df.reset_index() to create a new column in the DolphinDB table for the index.